# how to get a specific key from the ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, each

```
mike = {:911=>{"Id"=>"123"}}

sam =  {:sam_id=>"911", :sam_age=>"30", :sam_location=>"location", :sam_phone=>[{:no_1=>{:no_2=>"123"}}, {:locality=>"area"}]}


mike.each_key do | key |
  final_data = sam.find { |sams_data| sams_data[:sam_id].to_s == mike[key] }
end
```

how can I compare `|sams_data| sams_data[:mike_id].to_s == mike[key]`, since `mike[key]`  gives me the value `{"Id"=>"123"}` of that key which I don't want.

Comment: so actually I want 911 from mike = {:911=>{"Id"=>"123"}} and then compare it

Comment: That would be the `key`, buddy. This should work: `sams_data[:sam_id].to_s == key.to_s.to_i` (assuming that `sams_data[:sam_id]` is an integer)

Comment: that worked, thanks

Comment: Are you not getting an error about `:911`?

Comment: so in real senarion I have --> mike = {"911"=>{"Id"=>"123"}} and I am not getting any errors with that

Comment: You have `"911"` (a String) in _sam_ and `:911` (a Symbol) in _mike_. Since these are different values, you can't match them.

Comment: Edited. Please don't use the snippets feature for arbitrary code. Snippets are for runnable examples of html, css and javascript.

Comment: This is actually not valid Ruby. You can't write a symbol literal that begins with a number as in `:911`. While you can do this by adding quotes - `:"911"` it doesn't really make sense. I think most of your woes here are caused by the fact that you're mixing up symbols, strings and number keys.  Rails makes this beginner misstake easier to do since it uses HashWithIndifferentAccess in quite a lot of places so its usually a good idea to work on understanding the basic fundamentals of Ruby before you make a mess by adding the magic of Rails into the equation.